# Request.urlreferrer c#

Tags: c#, referrer, http-referer

What I need is the referrer to come up on Google Analytics that the traffic came from my website as it's source. Our software down-loader is working, but we need the show the providers that we sent the user to their download portal.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Very unclear what you are actually doing/trying to achieve. (In addition to post showing somewhat limited amount of research about the problem).

Comment: When someone downloads a software from our app, we want the users browser to open up the developers website and the provider can see we sent them the traffic to them on Google Analytics. At the moment the traffic is saying direct on Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the request referrer its kind of basic security issue, just like you can catch the url your users visit before the arrived to your application.

I think just like google does it ,you should redirect to url with parameters about the next url .
Now analytics will store those parameters as data which you can then filter and view your application redirect work.

Comment: webBrowser.Navigate(targetUrl, "_self", null, "Referrer: http://www.yourwebsite.com/");

Comment: How do I redirect to url with parameters about the next url?

Comment: You can send it in the url parameters .Abc.com?next=xyz.com google will save the "next" value for you